# Add value to table in SQL Server Reporting Services from other dataset

Tags: sql-server-2008, service, server, reporting

I'm working with SSRS for the first time. I want create table report but I have a data datatable from another project. I want add to table in report project. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you explain further? What do you mean by "a data datatable from another project"?

Comment: I get data from db up and execute some business after which i want to use the data to create report with SQL Server Reporting Services